# Colocar link para uma Window dentro de um TextBlock C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Olá! Tenho um poup-up e gostaria que ao ser apresentado a usuário possa clicar nele e ir direto ao Window referente, como posso inserir esse link dentro de uma string? É Possível? Minha aplicação e para desktop e estou utilizando C# e WPF

Comment: SIm, é possível. Utilize Hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Adicione um HyperLink no text block no formulário XAML com algumas funções como:
NavigateUri
RequestNavigate

Hyperlink.InLines que seria o texto do textblock

```
<TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink 
            NavigateUri="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/" 
            RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
            <Hyperlink.Inlines>
                <Run Text="Clique aqui"/>
            </Hyperlink.Inlines>
        </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Agora no arquivo cs crie um método  onde acontece o processo de navegação para a URL definida.

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e) => System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
```

referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092890/add-hyperlink-to-textblock-wpf